# Why isdigit() is not working properly in C

Tags: c

Why is `isdigit()` printing `0` (false) for both the integer and the character?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "with input of integer, output is %d\n", isdigit(1) );
    printf( "with input of char, output is %d\n", isdigit('k') );
}
```

Here is the output:

```
with input of integer, output is 0
with input of char, output is 0
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Try with character that represent digits: `isdigit('1')`.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, as I have now edited the question to replace the image with actual text. The specified closure reason problem does not seem applicable, as the problem was not caused by a typo and the problem is reproducible. The problem was caused by OP's lack of understanding of the difference between an integer and the character code of a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `isdigit` takes a character code as a parameter.

If you are using the [ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/) (you most likely are), then the character codes for the digits `0` to `9` are `48` to `57`. The character code for the digit `0` is `48` and the character code for the digit `9` is `57`.

Therefore, if you want to pass the digit `1` to the function `isdigit`, then you must pass the corresponding character code `49`, like this:

`isdigit( 49 )`

However, most programmers simply write

`isdigit( '1' )`

instead. The character literal `'1'` will evaluate to the corresponding character code `49` in this case, so both expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving 1 as character

try giving 1 as '1'

```
isdigit('1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the number 1 typically corresponds to the second character in the ASCII table (after 0) whereas the character '1' has ordinal 49. Therefor, what you want is `isdigit('1')`.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: To be annoyingly nitpicking, quoting the C Standard [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) at 7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`: "The  header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. *In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of  which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`*. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.".

Comment: @Bob__ Of course, I forgot this fact, thanks! I have updated the reply now.

Answer (score 2):

C does not automatically convert between numeric types and character types. If you give it a number where a character is expected it will take part of the number - I'm betting it's the low-order byte - and pass it to the function. But 0x01 is not the same as '1' - and thus `isdigit` correctly returns 0.

As others have noted, if you call `isdigit` with a correct character argument it will return the expected (non-zero) value.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
  {
  printf("isdigit(1) = %d\n", isdigit(1));
  printf("isdigit('1') = %d\n", isdigit('1'));
  printf("isdigit('k') = %d\n", isdigit('k'));

  return 0;
  }
```

When run at [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/rkrWZP_x_) this prints:

```
isdigit(1) = 0
isdigit('1') = 2048
isdigit('k') = 0
```

Comment: This one's so concise and well explained. +1

Answer (score 1):

These are the inputs which causes isdigit() to return an int 1:

ASCII-Codes for 0 - 9: 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57

Or as a character: '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'

For everything else, isdigit() will return int 0.